# facebook opengraph - How to query Friends and Myself

Tags: c#, xml, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a problem to display my name and my friends' names as individual Nodes, as I only get my friends' names without showing mine

```
  public JsonObject GetMyProfile(string accessToken)
              {               
                    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                    JsonObject me = client.Get("me/friends") as JsonObject;                  
                    return me;
              }
```

Right now this is the XML result I got
What I want is to display myself and my friends individually as a node

```
                - <icedata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="InformationConnectionsEngine.data">
    - <currentnode>
    + <node id="[{" name=":" gerald="" brisco="," 508219894="},{" helena="" tanvis="" loi="," 508637920="},{" maryam="" nasihah="," 514469729="},{" enguo="" teo="," 520924077="},{" kimberley="" xd="," 521541857="},{" noor="" haikal="," 522010705="},{" simin="" lim="," 524160253="},{" pam="" wong="," 524430008="},{" jiuying="" chen="," 531272219="},{" jeremy="" heng="" witha="" angmohname="," 531785558="},{" shanel="" see="," 533346883="},{" aaron="" 533822559="},{" soonboon="" kaichito="" mogu="," 534857954="},{" kai="" cannottank="," 537247625="},{" stacey="" goh="," 541347137="}&lt;/xml&gt;"></node></currentnode></icedata>
```

Comment: avoid using JsonObject, rather use IDictionary<string,object>. For array use IList<object>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make two distinct api calls: one to get your data, and another to get the friend list. Then you can put the two results together to build the xml.

The client.Get("me") call will result in a json with your data, and the client.Get("me/friends") will return a json where the attribute 'data' contains a list of objects like {id, name} (both as strings).